# how to create a file that could make it to call a specific database from mysql depends on what the user choose?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have made a cinema website and i am trying to add a function for suggestion movies, I have 4 options: Action, Adventure, Drama and Romantic. So for example if the user choose an action movie, i want to show some of the action movies in the side of the website (only action) same with the other. I have a specific key for each on, for Action: status = 0 (in mysql database) for Adventure: status = 1, 2 for Drama and 3 for Romantic. thanks

```
     if($status==1){
       $qry00=mysqli_query($con,"select * from where status=1 tbl_movie order by rand() limit 3");
     }
    elseif ($status==0) {
      $qry00=mysqli_query($con,"select * from where status=0 tbl_movie order by rand() limit 3");
    }
    elseif ($status==2) {
      $qry00=mysqli_query($con,"select * from where status=2 tbl_movie order by rand() limit 3");
    }
    elseif ($status==3) {
      $qry00=mysqli_query($con,"select * from where status=3 tbl_movie order by rand() limit 3");
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for the sql query? What have you tried?

Comment: I can show some random movies in the side of the website once you click on a specific movie. however, the movies are random movies, i want them to be depends on what type of the movie the user choose.I have tried if statement but i couldnt make it work

Comment: Please post your `if` statement so we can see why it doesn't work, then we can help you.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section, edit the question and add your code there. Also, it should be `$status`, not `status`, is it a copy paste mistake?

Comment: I did that, still not working -.-

Comment: Your SQL command is not valid, you need to specify the table name `select * from table_name where status=2 ...`

Comment: It just show random movies

Answer (score -1):

`switch` `case` maybe something you might need.

And specify your table name, you are requesting a query to nowhere

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM` **yourtablenamehere** `WHERE status=1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3"`